# Percentage for left style of a custom label in highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

In one of my highcharts charts, I have a label set up as follows:

```
labels: {
    items: [{
        html: 'All Industries',
        style: {
            left: '80%',
            top: '85px',
            color: 'black'
        }
    }]
}
```

I am finding that the label is only showing up about 15% of the way across the chart, rather than 80%. Now, it seems, the percentage is a percentage of SOMETHING, because if I set the percentage to, say, 550%, it will move to the right significantly. However, I can't figure out what exactly the percentage is being measured against. Anybody have any experience with this? Do you know how I can position this label 80% of the way across the chart area for a chart that's likely to be resized dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuantely percentage values are not supported, so need to be value in pixels.